# Adding "/" to strings if they are not already there

Tags: python

How do I add a `"/"` to the beginning and ending of a string in python? For example:

Input: `test`
Output: `/test/`

Input: `/test`
Output: `/test/`

Input: `test/`
Ouput: `/test/`

What's a neat way to do this? The only way I could think of was writing different `if` statements for each case. Surely, there's a better way to do this?

Comment: Why not strip them first?

Comment: 5 answers in less than a minute. intense

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Strip off any slashes from the existing string, then put two new ones around that.

```
text = "/%s/" % text.strip("/")
```

Comment: Anything "could" be removed in the future. I like `%` and will mourn the day it is removed. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Remove the old '/'s, if any, and then add them back:

```
'/' + s.strip('/') + '/'
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to do this, but the fastest (for the computer) is to simply test and augment each end.  Using **str** as the string:

```
if str[0] != '/':
    str = '/' + str
```

... and repeat for the other end.

Another way is to **strip** any existing slashes, and then add them to both ends.

If you know that there are no double-slashes within the string, you can add them and then replace doubles (in case you created them at the end):

```
str = '/' + str + '/'
str.replace('//', '/')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can strip the string first and then add '/' to beginning and end like this

```
'/' + <your_string>.strip('/') + '/'
```

Answer (score 0):

Well the following code solves the purpose of your question. You can simply use an or instead of separate if or elif statements.

```
def test(x):
    if x=="test" or x == "/test" or x=="test/":
        print("/",x.strip("/"),"/")
```